# Issues with string in structure in C codig

Tags: c, string, structure

I have some issues with strings in structure, i think that the problem is strcpy(), but i can't resolve it. My exercise says that i have to write a program that prints the distinct words given as input, sorted in order of frequency of decreasing occurrence and precede each word with its number of occurrences. I thought that scanf could do something wrong so i used fgets() to stdin to take my string from input, but it didnt resolve my problem :(. Here is my code (i haven't yet written the function that prints the words in order of frequency).

```
/*
Write a program that prints the distinct words given as input, sorted in order of frequency of
decreasing occurrence. Precede each word with its number of occurrences.
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define SIZE 30
#define MAXWORD 5

typedef struct word_dictionary{
    char ww[SIZE];
    int occ;
} word;

int is_in_bucket(char *str, word data[]){
    int j;

    for(j=0;j<MAXWORD;j++){
        if( strcmp(str,data[j].ww) == 0)
            return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}




void print_bucket(word data[]) {
    int i;
    
    for(i=0;i<MAXWORD;i++){
        printf("{%d, %s} ", data[i].occ, data[i].ww);
    }

    printf("\n");
}

void main( int argc, char **argv) {
    word bucket[MAXWORD];
    char aux[SIZE];
    int i;
    int x;
    int cond;

    for(i=0;i<MAXWORD;i++) {
        printf("Insert the word you want to save in the data structure: ");
        scanf("%s",aux);
        
        cond = is_in_bucket(aux,bucket);
        if(cond == 1) {
            bucket[i].occ = bucket[i].occ + 1;
            memset(aux,0,SIZE);
        } else {
            strcpy(bucket[i].ww, aux);
            bucket[i].occ = 1;
            memset(aux,0,SIZE);
        }
    }

    print_bucket(bucket);
    // print_occurrences();
    
    return;
}
```

My terminal output is:

> Insert the word you want to save in the data structure: dog
>
> Insert the word you want to save in the data structure: cat
>
> Insert the word you want to save in the data structure: dog
>
> Insert the word you want to save in the data structure: dog
>
> Insert the word you want to save in the data structure: mouse
>
> {1, dog} {1, cat} {-1768437999, } {1, V} {1, mouse}

My expected terminal output should be:

> Insert the word you want to save in the data structure: dog
>
> Insert the word you want to save in the data structure: cat
>
> Insert the word you want to save in the data structure: dog
>
> Insert the word you want to save in the data structure: dog
>
> Insert the word you want to save in the data structure: mouse
>
> {3, dog} {1, cat} {1, mouse}

Comment: Each empty line which you delete from your post will reduce how much you annoy people trying to read it. Also, please take the [tour].

Comment: The array used to gather input is on the stack, meaning it is uninitialised. It's no good searching for strings against a list of uninitialised "words"... Anything could happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters the function main shall have the return type int

```
int main( int argc, char **argv)
```

As the function parameters are not used then it is better to declare the function like

```
int main( void )
```

The function `is_in_bucket` does not take into account the number of actual initialized elements in the array `bucket`. You need to pass this  number to the function.

If a word is already present in the array it is not mean that it is stored exactly in the i-th element of the array.

```
    cond = is_in_bucket(aux,bucket);
    if(cond == 1){
        
        bucket[i].occ = bucket[i].occ + 1;
        memset(aux,0,SIZE);
```

You need to return form the function `is_in_bucket` the index of already initialized element or for example -1 otherwise.

Also the function `print_bucket` shall take into account the actual number of filled elements of the array `bucket`.